# QuickNote input in React losing focus after typing a single character

Tags: reactjs

am working on a React application where I am using a custom QuickNote component to take user input for a text area. However, I am facing an issue where the cursor disappears after typing a single character and the input box loses focus. I have tried various solutions such as checking for any conflicts in CSS, clearing the input box, and using other components instead of QuickNote, but the issue still persists. How can I fix this issue and ensure that the input box retains focus after user input

**Here is the quicknote componenet
**

```
const QuickNote = (props) => {
  const {
    onChange,
    quickNotesList,
    value,
    label,
    overriddenStyles,
    rows,
    cols,
    tabIndex,
    placeholder,
    autoFocus,
    fieldType,
    maxLength
  } = props;
  const textAreaRef = useRef(null);
  const quickNoteRef = useRef(null);
  const outerContainerRef = useRef(null);
  const [isOpenQuickNote, setIsOpenQuickNote] = useState(false);
  const [isTextAreaFocused, setIsTextAreaFocused] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    const clickFunction = (e) => {
      function isAncestor(nodeA, nodeB) {
        if (nodeA === null) {
          return false;
        }
        return nodeA === nodeB || isAncestor(nodeA.parentElement, nodeB);
      }

      let textAreaElement;
      if (
        e.target === textAreaRef.current ||
        e.target === outerContainerRef.current ||
        isAncestor(e.target, quickNoteRef.current)
      ) {
        textAreaElement = textAreaRef.current;
      }
      if (textAreaElement === undefined) {
        setIsOpenQuickNote(false);
        window.focus();
      }
    };
    document.body.addEventListener("click", clickFunction);

    return () => {
      document.body.removeEventListener("click", clickFunction);
    };
  }, []);

  const setQuickNote = (value) => {
    onChange(value);
  };

  const showNotes = (trigger) => {
    setIsOpenQuickNote(
      trigger || value === undefined || value === null || value.length === 0
    );
    setTimeout(() => quickNoteRef?.current?.focus(), 100);

    setIsTextAreaFocused(false);
  };

  return (
    <OuterContainer ref={outerContainerRef}>
      {fieldType === "input" ? (
        <InputFloatingLabel
          value={value}
          label={label}
          rows={rows}
          cols={cols}
          tabIndex={tabIndex}
          placeholder={placeholder}
          customRef={textAreaRef}
          overriddenStyles={overriddenStyles}
          onChange={onChange}
          autoFocus={autoFocus || isTextAreaFocused}
          onKeyDown={(e) => {
            if (e.ctrlKey) {
              if (e.keyCode === 40) {
                showNotes(true);
              }
            } else if (e.altKey) {
            } else {
              setIsOpenQuickNote(false);
            }
          }}
          onClick={(e) => {
            if (e.ctrlKey) {
              showNotes(true);
            }
          }}
          onFocus={() => {
            showNotes();
          }}
        />
      ) : (
        <TextareaFloatingLabel
          value={value}
          label={label}
          rows={rows}
          cols={cols}
          tabIndex={tabIndex}
          maxLength={maxLength}
          placeholder={placeholder}
          customRef={textAreaRef}
          overriddenStyles={overriddenStyles}
          onChange={onChange}
          autoFocus={autoFocus || isTextAreaFocused}
          onKeyDown={(e) => {
            if (e.ctrlKey) {
              if (e.keyCode === 40) {
                showNotes(true);
              }
            } else if (e.altKey) {
            } else {
              setIsOpenQuickNote(false);
            }
          }}
          onClick={(e) => {
            if (e.ctrlKey) {
              showNotes(true);
            }
          }}
          onFocus={() => {
            showNotes();
          }}
        ></TextareaFloatingLabel>
      )}

      {quickNotesList && quickNotesList.length && isOpenQuickNote ? (
        <QuickNoteDropDown
          quickNoteRef={quickNoteRef}
          quickNotesList={quickNotesList}
          setQuickNote={setQuickNote}
          setIsOpenQuickNote={setIsOpenQuickNote}
          value={value}
          maxLength={maxLength}
          setIsTextAreaFocused={setIsTextAreaFocused}
        />
      ) : null}
    </OuterContainer>
  );
};

const QuickNoteDropDown = (props) => {
  const {
    quickNoteRef,
    quickNotesList,
    setQuickNote,
    setIsOpenQuickNote,
    value,
    setIsTextAreaFocused,
    maxLength
  } = props;
  const [isDragging, setIsDragging] = useState(false);

  const handleClick = (e, x) => {
    if (isDragging) {
      setIsDragging(false);
      return;
    }
    if (!maxLength) {
      setQuickNote(value ? value.concat(x) : x);
    } else if ((maxLength - value.length) >= x.length) {
      setQuickNote(value ? value.concat(x) : x);
    }
    setIsOpenQuickNote(false);
    setIsTextAreaFocused(true);
  };
  return (
    <Draggable
      onDrag={() => {
        setIsDragging(true);
      }}
    >
      <Container ref={quickNoteRef}>
        <UnorderList>
          {quickNotesList.map((x) => {
            return (
              <RemarkItem
                isDragging={isDragging}
                onTouchEnd={(e) => handleClick(e, x)}
                onClick={(e) => handleClick(e, x)}
              >
                {x}
              </RemarkItem>
            );
          })}
        </UnorderList>
      </Container>
    </Draggable>
  );
};
```

**And above component i am using in different page**

```
<QuickNote
                              isTextAreaFocused={true}
                              value={damageComments}
                              label="Reason For Request"
                              placeholder="Reason..."
                              onChange={(value) => setDamageComments(value)}
                              maxLength="254"
                              overriddenStyles={{
                                outerContainer: {
                                  padding: "0.5rem 0.5rem 0.5rem 0"
                                },
                                input: {
                                  resize: "none",
                                  padding: "10px 15px"
                                },
                                label: { required: true }
                              }}
                            ></QuickNote>
```

**Here is the state variable for damageComments **

```
const [damageComments, setDamageComments] = React.useState("");
```

**and in the .then we are setting damageComments like below**

```
.then(() => {
        let body = {
          action: null,
          assetCoordinatorCode: acCode,
          assetCoordinatorName: acName,
          comments: damageComments,
          exceptionReasons: "",
          isReject: isRejected ? true : false,
          remark: isRejected ? "reject" : "approve",
          saveRequestCCSubInput: saveRequest
        };
```